# Images not Displayed when Published in IIS

Tags: asp.net

I have a web Application uses an image as the background of the menubar. This images is in Appthemes/Images folder. We are calling this image from CSS class as url(../App_Themes/Images/GridHeader.png);.
The same image is used as background for buttons and grid headers. 
I have  published it in IIS under the port 85. Then the images are showing correctly.
But I have to use 85 as a common port for different websites. So I created a virtual directory for this application in port 85. Now it can be accessed as 192.168.1.25:85/MyWebsite. Now background image for button is working correctly. But background image for menu bar and grid header  are not displaying. Plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible reason for this could be that the CSS would be in a sub-folder.